# Caching propertyinfo of abstract class

Tags: vb.net, caching, reflection, abstract-class

I've been playing around with implementing an abstract base class that using reflection accomplishes SQL to Object mapping.

I did some benchmarks and decided I wanted to implement a caching strategy for the property info of the objects (to prevent future lookups on them). My first instinct was to try and implement something like this.

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseModel
    Implements IFillable

    Private Shared PropertyCache As List(Of PropertyInfo)

    Sub New()
        PropertyCache = New List(Of PropertyInfo)
        For Each itm As PropertyInfo In Me.GetType().GetProperties
            PropertyCache.Add(itm)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

but then I realized that this would obviously not work because it would get overridden on subsequent object instantiations.

So now Im stuck, how can you implement an abstract class that caches its reflection "metadata"?

EDIT:

This is the best (workaround to my problem) I can come up with, Im hoping someone can suggest something better?

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseModel
    Implements IFillable

    Private Shared ReadOnly PropertyCache As New Dictionary(Of String, PropertyInfo)

    Sub New()
        Dim typeName As String = Me.GetType.ToString
        For Each itm As PropertyInfo In Me.GetType().GetProperties
            Dim lookupKey As String = String.Format("{0}_{1}", typeName, itm.Name)
            If Not PropertyCache.ContainsKey(lookupKey) Then
                PropertyCache.Add(lookupKey, itm)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

If you place the code in Shared Sub New instead it should only execute once.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711965(v=vs.71).aspx